# Displaying those Custom Meta Field with Value only in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress custom Meta Field and I want to display only those fields that have a value in it ( and not display those where the user has not put a value).

How I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code to display in if condition:

```
 <?php if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "field_name", true)): ?>

 <!-- here your html & meta echo or-->
 <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "field_name", true) ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```